# importing file from another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are multiple questions like this but and i tried every method from them i can't figure out why it is not working
i have file directory in "C" drive like this

PycharmProjects

```
          ├── pythonProject1
          │   └── test1.py
          └── pythonProject2
              └── test2.py
```

Now i want to import test1.py from pythonproject1 to pythonproject2 test2.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\jimmy\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1')
import test1
```

This code gives me error "No module named 'test1'"
i am using python 3.6 and have no "**init**" file in both folders, and if "**init**" file is needed how can i add that?

Comment: Have you tried with an empty `__init__.py` file inside pythonProject1 ?

Comment: You must have an __init__.py file in a projectx directory to import textx

Comment: `sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\jimmy\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1')` is really not how you should be handling this.

Comment: I have added ```__init__``` files but sill cannot import test1

Answer (score 1):

In your root directory add **init**.py

```
root
 ├── pythonProject1
          └── test1.py
          └── __init__.py
 └── pythonProject2
          └── test2.py
          └── __init__.py
 └── __init__.py
```

Once you do this directories will be treated as modules. __ init __ is just empty python file.

Answer (score 0):

this could work if "PycharmProjects" is the main Pycharm directory:

```
from PycharmProjects.pythonProject1 import test1
```

Comment: This is giving me this error "Unresolved reference 'PycharmProjects'"

Comment: PycharmProjects is inside "C" and PycharmProjects have both project1 and project2